# do i need to install WebSockets library for node?

Tags: node.js

I'm reading a book on using node.js for creating real time games.the problem is,it was published on 2011 with older version of node

for example it says :

> Next, we will install the WebSockets library for the Node.JS server.

is it still necessary to do this right now with node-v0.12.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NodeJS does not have a built-in websockets library as of v0.12.0. There are many plugins available, socket.io being one that is currently popular and IMO easy to use (express.io, which combines socket.io + express, is another one I use often when I want to mix http and ws protocols in a single app).

So the answer is: if you want websockets, then yes, you'll have to install *something*, and it's probably best to use the package / plugin / library that the book tells you too otherwise their code samples might not work (they might not work anyway, unless you go back and get the exact version(s) specified in the book.)

Comment: yes they may not work but i can use the overall process.any new ebooks on creating a multi-user sketchpad with js?

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not familiar with what ebooks are out there. As far as the *general* process of using websockets, that hasn't changed too much that I'm aware of in the last few years (much like the http 1.1 spec is still in use even though libraries and languages and hardware has all gotten better). Ws is just another protocol like http or ftp, except that instead of being "stateless" like http, it keeps a connection open btw client and server. This has many benefits: speed, less overhead, less code trying to mimic a stateful connection.